# Assembly -- syscall write returning -38, no output

Tags: linux, assembly, system-calls

I'm trying to learn some assembly, and I'm starting out by outputting text to the screen. I'm starting to think it might be my environment and/or compilation: by now, I'm so frustrated that I've literally copy-pasted assembly code but it just won't call the system calls. Here is the source code (mainly adapted from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Interfacing_with_Linux)

```
.section .data
msg: .ascii "Hello World\n"
.section .text

.global main
main: 
    movq $1, %rdi   # write to stdout
    movq $msg, %rsi # use string "Hello World"
    movq $12, %rdx  # write 12 characters
    syscall         # make syscall

    movq $60, %rax  # use the _exit syscall
    movq $0, %rdi   # error code 0
    syscall         # make syscall
```

I'm on a 64-bit machine running Kali Linux, and am compiling with GCC. Like so:

```
gcc -c test.s
gcc test.o -no-pie
```

I've debugged the program with GDB and the syscall instruction always sets the eax register to 0xffffffffffffffda (-38) which does not seem right...

Can anyone give an insight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Syscalls usually return a negative value in case of error, the absolute value being the `errno` value itself.

In your case `38`is `ENOSYS: Function not implemented`.

But what syscall function are you calling? Let's see, the function number is stored into `rax` (`eax` in 32-bits) before issuing the `syscall` and your program loads... nothing!

It looks like you lost one line in your copy/paste:

```
movq $1, %rax   ; use the write syscall
```

Comment: Oh i'm such a silly will sometimes... I guess I need to rest my eyes for a bit :). Anyhow, just one more thing: what's your reference for syscall error codes? How did you know that 38 equates to ENOSYS?

Comment: Nvm, I found them: http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html

Comment: In the old times I looked through the `/usr/include` headers or the `linux` ones. But now I've found a package named `moreutils` that, among other nice tools, contains a command `errno`. Just run `errno 38` and it does the hard work for you.

Comment: Beware of the `errno` lists in the Internet, because their numeric values are system specific, and can lend you to weird conclusions...

Comment: If you don't want to install anything, perl can convert error codes for you: `perl -E '$! = 38; say $!'`

Comment: thanks duskwuff and rodrigo. I'll be wary of the Internet when it comes to these low-level matters, and I apologize for the  somewhat obvious question

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing the first instruction from the sample code:

```
movq $1, %rax   ; use the write syscall
```

Without this code, it ends up executing an unexpected (and probably invalid) system call, based on whatever happened to be in `%rax` when `main` was called.